# MSVC: Bug with templated conversion operators and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, c++20, cl

I have the following code which does not compile with MSVC. It compiles fine with gcc, clang and icc. I guess it is a bug, right?

Do you have/know some workaround?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    template <
        typename C
        ,typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C, int>>
    >
    operator C() const{
        return 12;
    }
};

struct B
{
    template <
        typename C
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C, char>>
        , typename F = int
    >
    operator C() const
    {
        return 'A';
    }
};

struct AB : A, B
{
};

int main(){
    AB ab;
    int i = ab;
    char c = ab;
}
```

The error text is:

```
example.cpp

<source>(34): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'AB' to 'char'

<source>(34): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Compiler returned: 2
```

I already posted a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1158708/invalid-ambiguity-error-with-templated-conversion-operator.html) to Microsoft.

See it here on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xx7ceY)

Comment: For those of us without MSVC handy, it would help a lot if you showed the error that occurred.

Comment: You're right, but just in case you didn't know, godbolt has now the MSVC compiler, too.

Comment: Your use of [`enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is incorrect I think. You shouldn't constrain on a default value (see the example in the link marked "WRONG". There still seems to be an MSVC bug though.

Comment: This is the reason why B has an additional template parameter (F) which is acutally not used...

Comment: I really like cppreference and read that article, too. You can find under their sample that there is an ABI issue with non-type template parameters deduced to the same type (like int).

Therefore I prefer the usage of defaulted type parameters for SFINAE checks because they cause hard errors early. But with that solution you have to add some dummy types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems really to be a bug in MSVC. The last base seems not to be considered in operator template deduction process. For ex.

```
struct AB : A, B // -> only A's templated operator considered
struct AB  : B, A // -> only B's templated operator considered
```

In your case you could just remove the templated operators and use the types directly ([Live](https://godbolt.org/z/W44PeK)) ( using templates in this case doesn't make much sense anyway):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    operator int() const{ return 12;}
};

struct B
{
    operator char() const { return 'A'; }
};

struct AB : A, B
{
};

int main(){
    AB ab;
    int i = ab;
    char c = ab;
}
```

or you could move to class templates instead, something like ([Live](https://godbolt.org/z/738Yx8)):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
struct A
{
   
    operator T() const{
        return 12;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,char>>>
struct B
{
    operator T() const
    {
        return 'A';
    }
};

struct AB : A<int>, B<char>
{
};

int main(){
    AB ab;
    int i = ab;
    char c = ab;
}
```

or you could  overload templated operatros within single class ([Live](https://godbolt.org/z/9EjMsr)):

```
struct A
{
    template <
        typename C
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C, int>>
    >
        operator C() const {
        return 12;
    }

    template <
        typename C
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C, char>>
        , typename F = int
    >
        operator C() const
    {
        return 'A';
    }
};


struct AB : A
{
};

int main() {
    AB ab;
    int i = ab;
    char c = ab;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately my real case has not so simple SFINAE checks...

Answer (score 0):

I found a [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/MoKTKe).

Here you can see my solution. I changed my inheritance hierarchy and I introduced a forwarding conversion operator:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    template <
        typename C
        ,typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C, int>>
    >
    operator C() const{
        return 12;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    template <
        typename C
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same_v<C, char>
        >
    >
    operator C() const
    {
        return 'A';
    }

    template <
        typename C
        , typename Base = A
        , typename = std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_convertible_v<Base, C>
            &&
            !std::is_same_v<C, char>
        >
    >
    operator C() const
    {
        return static_cast<C>(*static_cast<const Base*>(this));
    }
};

struct AB : B
{
};

int main(){
    AB ab;
    int i = ab;
    char c = ab;
}
```